# Slave a computer screen display through USB port

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, vga, external-display, dell-optiplex

I usually slave my university computer displays by hooking up a vga cable from my laptop to the screen, but recently the uni has upgraded their PCs and the vga ports are hidden behind a locked port cover.

The only ports available are USB ports (on a Dell Optiplex 9010). Is there a way to slave these computer displays through the USB port rather than their vga port?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you talking about a USB port on the PC? Or a USB port on the monitor?

Comment: It is an all in one PC and the USB is on the monitor - all the other ports are covered by a plastic port cover that I cannot access (without damaging the thing!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.
The USB port on the monitor is simply a hub that extends an existing USB port. The USB port on the screen is not tied into the actual video portion of the screen in any way that would allow you to use the port in the fashion you desire.